# how to get Data dynamically from Firebase Database

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I've been trying to learn using firebase database for my projects. however, I cannot get it to work as there seems to be an error with reading the data from my firebase.

I've only been watching video tutorials and reading some information from the internet so I'm still not sure what I'm doing. If anyone could pinpoint the actual error in my code, I'll be very grateful.

[image: Here is how it looks like in the database]

```
        const db = getDatabase();
        var tBody = document.querySelector("#tbody1");
        var appointmentID = 0;
        tBody.innerHTML = "";

        function AddRequestToTable(name, email, phone, date, time, service, status) {
            let tRow = document.createElement("tr");
            let td1 = document.createElement("td");
            let td2 = document.createElement("td");
            let td3 = document.createElement("td");
            let td4 = document.createElement("td");
            let td5 = document.createElement("td");
            let td6 = document.createElement("td");
            let td7 = document.createElement("td");

            td1 = ++appointmentID;
            td2 = name;
            td3 = email;
            td4 = phone;
            td5 = date + " " + time;
            td6 = service;
            td7 = status;

            tRow.appendChild(td1);
            tRow.appendChild(td2);
            tRow.appendChild(td3);
            tRow.appendChild(td4);
            tRow.appendChild(td5);
            tRow.appendChild(td6);
            tRow.appendChild(td7);

            tBody.appendChild(tRow);
        }

        function AddAllRequeststoTable(AppointmentRequests) {
            tBody.innerHTML = "";

            AppointmentRequests.array.forEach((element) => {
                AddRequestToTable(
                    element.name,
                    element.email,
                    element.phone,
                    element.date,
                    element.time,
                    element.service,
                    element.status,
                );
            });
        }

        function GetAllDataOnce() {
            const dbRef = ref(db, "appointmentForm");

            get(dbRef, child(db)) = ((snapshot) => {
                var requests = [];

                snapshot.forEach((childSnapshot) => {
                    requests.push(childSnapshot.val());
                });
                AddAllRequeststoTable(requests);
            });
        }

        window.onload = GetAllDataOnce();
```

and it says that the error is somewhere in this part...

```
function GetAllDataOnce() {
            const dbRef = ref(db, "appointmentForm");

            get(dbRef, child(db)) = ((snapshot) => {
                var requests = [];

                snapshot.forEach((childSnapshot) => {
                    requests.push(childSnapshot.val());
                });
                AddAllRequeststoTable(requests);
            });
        }
```

I tried what I can for more than 12 hours now, and still to no avail.

Comment: "it says that the error is somewhere in this part" Is there an error message? If so, can you edit your question to include that (with its stack trace)?

Answer (score 0):

your GetAllDataOnce should be something lit the following:

```
const dbRef = ref(getDatabase());    
get(child(dbRef, `DBName/${childUID}`)).then((snapshot) => {
    
    }
```